# エイトクイーンパズルの解法について

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

「アルゴリズムとデータ構造」紀平拓男／春日伸弥 著 （http://www.sbcr.jp/products/4797324198.html?sku=4797324198）第10章において
エイトクイーンパズルをC言語で解いているのですが、

左上(0, 0)がクイーンの場合しか答えを出力しない

のはどうしてか教えてください。また、

他の91通りの解を出力するにはどのように修正すればよいか

も教えていただけないでしょうか？

ちなみに以下のコードは、本の解法をRuby版にかなり忠実に置き換えたものです。
（コードの重複等あるかと思いますが、あらかじめご了承ください。）

ご指摘や、コードの修正は、こちらのRuby版で行なっていただけると
ありがたいです。

```
@board = Array.new(8, false)
@board.each_index do |i|
  @board[i] = Array.new(8, false)
end

# (x,y)にクィーンがあるかどうかチェック
def check(x, y)
  # 左方向をチェック
  p = 0
  while p < x
    return false if @board[p][y]
    p += 1
  end  
  # 左上方向をチェック
  p, q = x, y
  while p > 0 && q > 0
    return false if @board[p -= 1][q -= 1]
  end 
  # 左下方向をチェック
  p, q = x, y
  while p > 0 && q < 7
    return false if @board[p -= 1][q += 1]
  end

  return true
end

def showBoard
  for y in (0..7)
    for x in (0..7)
      if @board[x][y]
        printf "Q "
      else
        printf ". "
      end
    end
    printf "\n"
  end
end

def solve(x)
  if x == 8
    return true
  end

  i = 0
  while i < 8
    if check(x, i)
      # (x,i)にクィーンがおけたら実際に置く
      @board[x][i] = true
      if solve(x + 1)
        # 次の列以降が成功ならこの列も成功
        return true
      else
        # 次の列以降が失敗ならクィーンを置き直す
        @board[x][i] = false
      end
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return false
end

if solve(0)
  showBoard
  puts "---------------"
end
```

Comment: 「アルゴリズムとデータ構造」は紀平拓男氏の書籍かと思われますが、Amazonや紀伊國屋書店のウェブページへのリンクも記載していただけませんか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

質問のコードは `solve(x)` で`x`列目の上から`i`行目にクィーンをセットしてみて、
`solve(x + 1)` を呼び出し`x + 1`列より先にクィーンを配置することが可能かどうかを再帰的にテストしています。
`solve(x + 1)` が `false` を返している場合は`i`番目に配置したクィーンを元に戻してから`i + 1` 番目をテストをしていますが、
`true` が帰ってきた場合はそこで処理を終了してしまっているので、１つ解が見つかってしまえばそこで処理が終了してしまいます。

全ての解が求めたいのであれば、解が見つかった場合にも `false` の場合と同じように i 番目に配置したクィーンを元に戻して
`i + 1` 番目に置いた場合も試すように変更してあげる必要があります。

solve が `x == 8` になり再帰の終端に達した時が、エイトクィーンの解が見つかった時なので
`if x == 8` の中で盤面を表示し、その回数を `num_results` で数えるように修正すればよいです。
この場合 `solve(x + 1)` の返り値をチェックする必要は特にないので `solve` の返り値は不要です。
質問のオリジナルのコードをなるべく維持したまま修正するなら次のようになります。

```
@board = Array.new(8, false)
@board.each_index do |i|
  @board[i] = Array.new(8, false)
end

# (x,y)にクィーンがあるかどうかチェック
def check(x, y)
  # 左方向をチェック
  p = 0
  while p < x
    return false if @board[p][y]
    p += 1
  end  
  # 左上方向をチェック
  p, q = x, y
  while (p > 0) && (q > 0)
    return false if @board[p -= 1][q -= 1]
  end
  # 左下方向をチェック
  p, q = x, y
  while p > 0 && q < 7
    return false if @board[p -= 1][q += 1]
  end

  return true
end

def showBoard
  for y in (0..7)
    for x in (0..7)
      if @board[x][y]
        printf "Q "
      else
        printf ". "
      end
    end
    printf "\n"
  end
end

$num_results = 0

def solve(x)
  if x == 8
    # 解が１つ見つかった
    showBoard
    puts "---------------"
    $num_results += 1
  end

  i = 0
  while i < 8
    if check(x, i)
      # (x,i)にクィーンがおけたら実際に置く
      @board[x][i] = true
      # (x,i)にクィーンを置いた状態で x + 1 に解があるか調べる
      solve(x + 1)
      @board[x][i] = false
    end
    i += 1
  end
end

solve(0)
puts $num_results
```

Comment: 処理を終了させない方法（回答していただいたの方法）のほうが、コードがスッキリしている感じがします。

Answer (score 2):

質問文にあるコードでは、大きく２つの問題があります。

１．howBoard 一回しか よばれていません。
solve(x) の中で x == 8 の時は すべての列にクィーンが置けた状態になったので、、その時点で showBoard することが必要です。

2. solve(x) の中で x == 8 の時に true を返しており、次のクィーンの置き方を試すようになっていません。

これらを修正する、コードの重複を除去する、 8-クィーンだけでなく4-クィーンなど他の N-クィーン問題も解けるようにする などの変更をしてみました。
(さらに少しの工夫を加えることで、ボードを回転させた時に同じになる解を取り除くことも可能です)
実行すると 92 個も解が表示されます。

```
# coding: utf-8

# See https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/3021  エイトクイーンパズルの解法について

# ボードの 1 辺のサイズ
N = 8 # 4

# 解の数を 0 に設定する。
@count = 0

# ボードを空に設定する。
@board = Array.new(N) { Array.new(N, false) }

# ボード上のクィーンの配置を表示する。
def showBoard
  (0..N - 1).each do |y|
    (0.. N - 1).each do |x|
      printf @board[x][y]? 'Q ' : '. '
    end
    printf "\n"
  end
end

# (x, y) にクィーンが置けるかどうかチェック
def check(x, y)

  dys = [
    -1,   # 左上方向を調べるための行位置の変化
    0,    # 左方向を調べるための　行位置の変化
    1     # 左下方向を調べるための行位置の変化
  ]
  dys.each do |dy|
    (1..x).each do |dx|
      x1 = x - dx
      y1 = y + dy * dx
      return false if (0 <= y1) && (y1 < N) && @board[x1][y1]
    end
  end
  true
end

def solve(x)
  if x == N
    # すべての列にクィーンを置けたので、解を表示する。
    @count += 1
    printf "#{@count} --------\n"
    showBoard
  else
    # (x, 0) ... (x, N-1) にクィーンを置くことを試していく。
    (0..N - 1).each do |i|
      if check(x, i)
        # (x, i) にクィーンが置けるので、実際に置く。
        @board[x][i] = true

        # 次の列に進む
        solve(x + 1)

        # (x, i) に置いたクィーンを取り除く。
        @board[x][i] = false
      end
    end
  end
end

# N  クィーン問題を解く。
solve(0)
```